# Showing success message logs on Jest

Tags: javascript, jestjs

I wonder about the logs of success messages when the test is being successful. When Jest is finished the test, Jest just showing the failure message and not for success message. Can I config jest to showing success message too from assertion ?

```
expect.extend({
            valueEqualTo(received, validator){
                if(validator == received){
                    return {
                        message : () => `Value ${received} is equal to validator`,
                        pass : true
                    }
                }else {
                    return {
                        message : () => `Value ${received} is not equal to validator`,
                        pass : false 
                    }
                }
            }
        });
```

When success (Jest is not showing the success message from assertion)
[image]

When failed (Jest showing the failure message from assertion)
[image]

Comment: What success message do you expect?

Comment: I expect my success message that from expect will be appear on console, as same as error message appear on console

Answer (score 0):

you can use `--verbose` to showing success message logs on Jest so following this config in package.json

```
"scripts": {
   "test": "jest --watchAll --no-cache --verbose"
}
```